How to untar with excluding one top level folder
I want to exclude the ".git" from untar, but without success.
Here is the folder structure:
mkdir -p /tmp/test

mkdir -p /tmp/test/.git/hi
touch /tmp/test/.git/foo.bar

touch /tmp/test/.git_others.txt
touch /tmp/test/.gitok.txt
touch /tmp/test/.git.txt
touch /tmp/test/.git/hi/hello.txt

mkdir -p /tmp/test/hello
touch /tmp/test/hello/.git

touch /tmp/test/hello/world.txt

mkdir -p /tmp/test/hello/bar/.git
touch /tmp/test/hello/bar/fine.ok
touch /tmp/test/hello/bar/.git/yes.txt

touch /tmp/test/root.yes

Here is the tar file content:
# tar -tf /tmp/test.tar.gz

.git/
.git/hi/
.git/hi/hello.txt
.git/foo.bar
.gitok.txt
.git_others.txt
.git.txt
hello/
hello/.git
hello/bar/
hello/bar/fine.ok
hello/bar/.git/
hello/bar/.git/yes.txt
hello/world.txt
root.yes

This command is trying to exclude ".git" folder, but it will exclude all ".git"s, including the following folders and files: ".git/*", "hello/.git", and "hello/bar/.git/*"
# tar --exclude=".git" -xzvf "/tmp/test.tar.gz"

.gitok.txt
.git_others.txt
.git.txt
hello/
hello/bar/
hello/bar/fine.ok
hello/world.txt
root.yes

This command is trying to exclude path starts with ".git" and ends with "/", but it doesn't seem to match the regex at all:
# tar --exclude="^.git/$" -xzvf "/tmp/test.tar.gz"

.git/
.git/hi/
.git/hi/hello.txt
.git/foo.bar
.gitok.txt
.git_others.txt
.git.txt
hello/
hello/.git
hello/bar/
hello/bar/fine.ok
hello/bar/.git/
hello/bar/.git/yes.txt
hello/world.txt
root.yes

Here is the expected output:
# tar --exclude="???" -xzvf "/tmp/test.tar.gz"

.gitok.txt
.git_others.txt
.git.txt
hello/
hello/.git
hello/bar/
hello/bar/fine.ok
hello/bar/.git/
hello/bar/.git/yes.txt
hello/world.txt
root.yes

How to write the  --exclude="???"  for excluding only the top level ".git"?

It seems that ^.git/ or even ./.git/ works in bsdtar (libarchive), but not GNU tar.

Actually, I think --anchored --exclude=".git" is probably what you need.

@TomYan, Thank you. I tried the --anchored --exclude=".git", it works! Please add your comment as answer then I can accept.

Apparently GNU tar would matches all directories (and probably files, if any) named .git when you have --exclude=".git", but not those that the name merely "consists of" .git. Content under the matched directories would be excluded as well.
To exclude only the .git "at the top", there's --anchored:

  --anchored
         Patterns match file name start.


bsdtar (libarchive) seems to work pretty differently though. It seems that both ^.git/ and ./.git/ (even if you don't see leading ./ in -tf) would have worked for it.
